# Erro mascara JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Bom estou tendo problemas com a mascara do javascript para o campo telefone, estou desenvolvendo mobile e estou utilizando os códigos abaixo.

código do input:

```
<input type="text" name="telefone" id="telefone" maxlength="15"/>
```

código javascript

```
$('#telefone').mask('(00) 0000-00009');
$('#telefone').blur(function(event) {
   if($(this).val().length == 15){ // Celular com 9 dígitos + 2 dígitos DDD e 4 da máscara
      $('#telefone').mask('(00) 00000-0009');
   } else {
      $('#telefone').mask('(00) 0000-00009');
   }
});
```

Erro no console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function //Erro na linha do .maks(...)
```

O que pode ser ? E como concertar, alguem tem alguma ideia melhor ?

Estou precisando que ele verifica se existe alguma letra e propriamente dito uma mascara.

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Tens o `plugin` carregado ?

Comment: Parece estar executando  antes do corpo completar o carregamento. Então não encontra o objeto `$('#telefone')` e por isso fica algo como `undefined.mask('(00) 0000-00009')`.. É óbvio que não vai existir nenhuma função/método para `undefined`.. Mas é apenas uma suspeita. Pode ser outra causa.

Comment: Daniel, provavelmente pode ser isto mesmo. Irei verificar ao chegar em casa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve de estar esquecendo de adicionar a chamada da biblioteca

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mask.min.js"/></script>
```

Aí é só fazer algo assim

```
<label for="txttelefone">Telefone</label>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">$("#txttelefone").mask("(00) 0000-00009");</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Verifica se você colocou o plugin jQuery e o Masked Input nessa ordem, depois inicie o ***plugin*** dentro de:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#telefone').mask('(00) 0000-00009'); 
    });
}).(jQuery);
```

Veja [esta página](http://www.sitepoint.com/5-ways-declare-functions-jquery/), exemplo 4.